# Anybody seen this? Reboot loop when entering Audit Mode?

Tags: windows-7, hp, desktop, sysprep

We have a production system in place that requires users to enter Audit Mode a few times during a computer refurbishing process.

Most machines we get are in OOBE mode when we get them, and the current instruction is to Ctrl+Shift+F3 into audit mode to look up the vital stats on the machine before it is reimaged.

On a handful of HP desktop or all-in-ones, when they attempt to go into Audit Mode, the machine starts into a reboot loop.  It will briefly show the desktop, but then reboot again and continue rebooting.  I'm kind of at a loss on this one.  Google was not very helpful - this seems to happen a lot when doing as sysprep and getting an error, but we're not doing a sysprep on these machines.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just reimaging the machine anyway, I would suggest you ignore and work around it.

For instance, skip the boot into Windows step and boot [WinPE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Preinstallation_Environment) instead to gather the information you're looking for.

Comment: That's essentially what we're doing as a workaround.  However I still need to find a resolution to this issue if possible.

My hunch is that the machines we're getting might be getting factory restored from a restore partition, and someone rolled these images up and ignored the sysprep error.  That's the only thing that makes sense to me.  But if anyone has a fix for this, I'm all ears.